# Unable to call WCF service on different server

Tags: .net, wcf, http-status-code-503

We are unable to invoke WCF service on remote server. It is working fine whenever we restart that server.Whenever we deploy new code for this services project using teamcity then again the problem starts.

Note: If we invoke same WCF service using SOAPUI from same machine where services are hosted then we are getting response from service. but when we do the same from another system then we are not getting any response.

Comment: Just to clarify, it _will_ work over the network _after_ you restart the server?

Comment: what is the error? are you trying to access by ip or dns?

Comment: Yes, it works over the network once I restart the server. I am accessing through dns.

Comment: Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue is logged in httperr3.log for that particular service.